# How to change character to numeric vector in R

Tags: r, string, vector, character, numeric

Given `a`, I have to return  `b`:

```
a <- "[1, 2, 3]"   # class: character
b <- c(1, 2, 3)    # class: numeric
```

I have tried `strsplit()` and  `paste()` functions but both are not working well. Can I get some help?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that this is from a JSON source, so there are packages for that:

```
 library(jsonlite) # obviously needs to be installed first

fromJSON(a)
#[1] 1 2 3
```

JSON files always are read into R functions from type character but the converted to R objects with typing conventions like that of read.table.

Comment: This is probably the best answer +1.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the string with `gsub`, split it on comma and convert it to numeric.

```
b <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', a), ',\\s+')))
b
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do a regex find all to extract all digits.  Then, cast the character vector output to numeric:

```
a <- "[1, 2, 3]"
b <- as.numeric(regmatches(a, gregexpr("[0-9]+", a))[[1]])
b

[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`stringr` (`tidyverse`) way of doing it

```r
library(stringr)
a <- "[1, 2, 3]"

str_split(a, ',') %>% unlist %>%
  str_replace('\\D*(\\d*)\\D*', '\\1') %>%
  as.numeric()
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>